# CURLOPT_TIMEOUT is not working in curl 7.51.0 version

Tags: curl

I am trying to use CURLOPT_TIMEOUT in multi curl request. But it's not working. The whole process is getting block after timeout reach.Is there a way to set a timeout for each handle to avoid an endless loop? What else could I do to fix this problem?